# Python. Getting urls from page

Tags: python, html, parsing, sitemap

This code parses the page and extracts the url to generate the sitemap. Along with the url, I also take away a part of the js code. How to flicker to exclude js ?

```
if (resp.status == 200 and
        ('text/html' in resp.headers.get('content-type'))):
    data = (await resp.read()).decode('utf-8', 'replace')
    urls = re.findall(r'(?i)href=["\']?([^\s"\'<>]+)', data)
    asyncio.Task(self.addurls([(u, url) for u in urls])
```

Comment: Can you provide some input data and expected output

Comment: Parsing http://google.com I get:


http://google.com/f},0)};}).call(this);

http://google.com/intl/pl/policies/terms/

http://google.com/intl/pl/policies/privacy/

http://google.com/intl/pl/policies/terms/url}}catch(e){}if(window.location.hash)url+=window.location.hash;window.location.href=url;

http://google.com/preferences?hl=pl

http://google.com/intl/pl/policies/privacy/url}}catch(e){}if(window.location.hash)url+=window.location.hash;window.location.href=url;

http://google.com/_.Vc(b)}

Comment: Expected output is links without js

Comment: You are using `bs4` ? or any other module

Comment: I'm using aiohttp, asyncio